# multilingual model attributes in sails js advice

Tags: internationalization, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm about to start a project that's going to require some attributes on a model to be translated and not sure what the best approach would be.

One option would be to create a JSON type attribute and store the translations as

```
{ 
title: [{ "en": "cheese" }, {"de": "Käse"}, {"es": "queso"}, etc... ]
}
```

but I'm also wondering if would be better to store these values in a separate collection and create an association, then when getting the parent model I could just populate with the appropriate language. So something like

Product Model

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
     sku: 'string',
     values:{
        collection: 'productValues',
        via: 'product'
     }
  }
}
```

Product Values Model

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
     title: 'string',
     body: 'string',
     language: 'string',
     product:{
        model: 'product'
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just add a JSON for translations to the model.

```
 module.exports = {
  attributes: {
     defaultValue: 'string',
    translations: 'json'
  }
}
```

Then you could simply work with the translation object. Delete translations, add new ones etc.

```
Model.findById(id).then(function(record){
  var translations = record.translations;
  translations.en = 'Hello';
  delete translations.fr;
  Model.update({id: id},{translations: translations}, function(){});
});
```

(Just an example code, didnt test it)
But if you want 1 translation to work with multiple records than it is insufficient. And then you could create seperate collection for translations and reference records of it as needed.